# How can I change specific letters color what I put into the inputbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I'd like to make effect above using input. I can make only change text color no matter what I put into inputbox, not specific letters. I'd like to make specific letters' color change what I write on the inputbox. For example, if I put "hello" into the inputbox, The colors of "H", "E", "L", "L", "O" turn green. here's my code below.

```js
  document.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.getElementById('values').style.color = "#999";
  });
```

```css
    body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <h1 id="values"><span class="Q">Q</span><span class="W">W</span><span class="R">R</span><span class="T">T</span></h1>
   <input type="text" id="inp">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Created a small snippet below to implement what you need I think :-

```js
inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const word = document.getElementById('values');
  [...word.children].forEach((letter) => {
    if (e.target.value.includes(letter.textContent)) {
      letter.style.color = '#999';
    } else {
      letter.style.color = "#222";
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="values"><span class="Q">Q</span><span class="W">W</span><span class="R">R</span><span class="T">T</span></h1>
  <input type="text" id="inp">
</body>

</html>
```

**Explanation** - We are getting the whole `word` by getting the `values` element since it's the **parent** of your `letters` represented by individual `span` elements. Then we are iterating over the `children` of word i.e. for each `letter` we are checking whether that's included in the **text** we just typed or not. If it is, style it to **highlight color** else to **default color**.

Note - Currently it's **case-sensitive** so **q & Q are different** (can be easily resolved by using `.toUpperCase()/.toLowerCase()` on both sides of comparisons). Also it's searching for all occurrences of a letter so it will highlight all letters that match a particular letter from your input. So you would need additional logic to only highlight a single letter which hasn't been highlighted before.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   $(function(){
    $('#inp').on('keyup',function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    key= String.fromCharCode(key);
    $('.'+key.toString()).css({'color':'red'});
});
});
```

```js
$(function(){
$('#inp').on('keyup',function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key != 8 && key != 16)
    {
    key= String.fromCharCode(key);
    $('.'+key.toString()).css({'color':'red'});
    }
});
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
   <h1 id="values"><span class="Q">Q</span><span class="W">W</span><span class="R">R</span><span class="T">T</span></h1>
   <input type="text" id="inp">
</body>
</html>
```

You can use jquery for this.[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q9ajnyeL/)

In this demo you can use both uppercase and lowercase letters.

Comment: throws an error after filling the whole QWRT red

Comment: @FlashThunder Fixed the error, thank you for pointing out.